# mail postfix/smtpd[53278]: warning: connect to Milter service inet:127.0.0.1:8893: Connection refused

Tags: postfix

This issue arose after upgrading my ubuntu release to 20.04 in  steps from 14.04 I'm using libmilter1.0.1

Comment: You may want to reference [this ServerFault post](https://serverfault.com/questions/858879/postfix-connect-to-milter-service-inet127-0-0-18891-connection-refused), as your issue appears to be identical. **TLDR:** `sudo nano /etc/default/opendkim`, edit the `SOCKET` setting, then restart opendkim with `sudo service opendkim restart`.

Comment: So what should I set Socket to? It's already set to local: /run/opendkim/opendkim.sock

Comment: None of that worked so I purged and reinstalled opendkim Still not working